# Can not match multiple "attributes" in "[shortcode attr=value attr=value]" string with REGEX in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

`[jeans size="L"]
 [jeans color="blue" size="XL"]`

And the following regex which I run through PHP's preg_match_all():

`#\[(?P<tag_name>\w+)(?:\s*(?P<attr>\w+)\s?[=,:]\s?["\'](?P<value>\w*)["\'])*\s*]#igs`

I've tried many variations of the regex and can't seem to get the multiple attributes of a given shortcode, e.g. the color and the size in the second one. Only the last attribute is retrieved per tag.

Here is a fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/hF1tS1/5

[image]

Comment: I realized after commenting that you weren't looking for *specific* attributes; that's why the comments not there anymore. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
\[(?P<tag_name>\w+)\K|\G(?!^)(?:\s*(?P<attr>\w+)\s?[=,:]\s?["\'](?P<value>\w*)["\'])
```

You can make use of  `\G assert position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match` here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/33

Comment: Is there a way to do this without breaking the default behavior of PHP's preg_match_all(). By default it selects the full match of the expression in $matches[0].

Comment: @hasMobi-AndroidApps i dont have any idea about that but `matches[0]` can be ignored easily

Comment: What I meant is could I somehow group all attributes of a single shortcode in a single match instead of having separate matches for each attribute inside the shortcode?

Comment: @hasMobi-AndroidApps i dont think its possible .It will give all atribut value groups together which i guess would not be of use to you